# Answer to "What day are you leaving?"

Tags: dates

If someone asks "What day are you leaving?", would it be grammatically correct to answer with "On the 8th April." for example? Or does it have to be "On Monday."?

Comment: You can say "on the 8th of April" or "on April 8th" or "on April 8" or "on 8 April" ... and why do you think "on Monday" would be a replacement for any of those?

Comment: I had an English test today and my teacher said that "On the 8th of April." is incorrect. But I don't know how I can prove that it's correct to him. If you can help me by telling exactly why it would be correct, I would love you forever.

Comment: "On the 8th April" is wrong, but "On the 8th of April" is correct.  If your teacher literally said that that was incorrect, either there was a misunderstanding, or he doesn't know what he is talking about.  Unfortunately there are a lot of bad English teachers out there.

Comment: The 8th April would be in eight years, so that would give urgent meaning to "What day are you leaving?"  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question of what's technically correct versus what's commonly used.

**Common usage:**

What day are you leaving? 
Monday / next Monday / On the 8th of April.

No one really asks "On what date are you leaving?' even though it's technically correct.

**Technically correct:**

What day are you leaving? 
Answer should be a day of the week

What date are you leaving on?
The 8th of April.

Answer (score 0):

Often, when people ask the day, it's the day of the week (Monday). When they ask for the date they are looking for the actual date, April 8th, in your example. A simple way to avoid confusion is to give both answers, "Monday, April 8th".